# Unable to append RichTextBox text in Cross-Thread operation VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'am coding a Multi-Threaded TCP echo server, but the problem is when i call UpdateMessage from ClientHandler class, the RichTextBox's text is not appending.

This is the Form1 class that containts the RichTextBox1

Public Class Form1

```
Const PORT As Integer = 1234 'The port number on which the server will listen for connection.
Dim ServerSocket As New TcpListener(PORT) 'The Server Socket that will listen for connections on specified port number.

Dim Link As TcpClient 'The Socket that will handle the client.

Dim NumberOfClients As Integer = 0 'The total number of clients connected to the server.


Dim myThread As Thread 'The thread on which the server will handle the client


Dim sc As SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current

Public Clienthandler As ClientHandler

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    ServerSocket.Start()
    ' UpdateMessage("Server started..")


    myThread = New Thread(AddressOf AcceptClients) 'Handle the client in a different thread
    myThread.Start()


    btnStart.Text = "Started!"
    btnStart.Enabled = False

End Sub




Private Sub AcceptClients()


    'Keep accepting and handling the clients.
    While (True)
        Link = ServerSocket.AcceptTcpClient() 'Accept the client and let the Socket deal with it.
        NumberOfClients = NumberOfClients + 1 'update the total number of clients

        Dim ClientAddress As String = Link.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString

        '  UpdateMessage("Client number " & NumberOfClients & " connected from " & ClientAddress)


        Clienthandler = New ClientHandler
        Clienthandler.StartClientThread(Link, NumberOfClients)



        Me.sc.Post(AddressOf Clienthandler.UpdateMessage, "Client number " & NumberOfClients & " connected from " & ClientAddress)

    End While

    'close the sockets

    Link.Close() 'close the Socket.
    ServerSocket.Stop() 'Stop the Server Socket.

End Sub
```

End Class

And here is the ClientHandler class:

Public Class ClientHandler

```
Private Link As TcpClient
Private ClientNumber As Integer
Dim NumberOfMessages As Integer = 0 'The number of messages that client has sent.
Dim Stream As NetworkStream 'The stream being used for sending/receiving data over Socket.


Dim scHandler As SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current

Public Sub StartClientThread(Link As TcpClient, ClientNumber As Integer)

    'Initialize the class variables with the arguments passed in StartClient 

    Me.Link = Link
    Me.ClientNumber = ClientNumber



    'Start the thread

    Dim ClientThread As New Thread(AddressOf Chat)
    ClientThread.Start()

    UpdateMessage("Thread for client " & ClientNumber & " started!")



End Sub
```

Public Sub UpdateMessage2(Message As String)

```
    Me.scHandler.Post(AddressOf UpdateMessage2, Message)
End Sub
Public Sub UpdateMessage(Message As String)

    Message = vbNewLine & Trim(Message)

    If Message.Length < 1 Then
        Message = "empty"
    End If

    MessageBox.Show("Updating message!" & vbNewLine & Message)


    Form1.RichTextBox1.AppendText(Message)





End Sub
```

The same problem still exits, the RichTextBox is being updated from UI Thread only.

Comment: Using the *type name* Form1 where an *object reference* is needed is a VB.NET trap.  It stops working when you do that in a thread, it creates a *new* object of type Form1.  One you can't see and doesn't match the one you are looking at.  You have to use a proper object reference.

Comment: also, i just wanted to point out that the textbox code should be in the base class of whatever it is you're coding. ie: `myClass` would contain a member `TextBox`, as well as the thread class and methods. then add the `TextBox` control from your class to `Form1`. that way you have a ref to the textbox in the thread class. plus, all of the code for your object/controls is in one class/namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be a bit more specific than Hans Passant, using the form name where an object is expected makes use of the default instance of the form, which is an instance that the system creates and manages for you.  The default instance is thread-specific though, which means that there is one default instance per thread.  If you use the default instance in a secondary thread then you are using a different object to the one that you displayed on the UI thread.  You might read a bit more about default instances here:

http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html

You need to somehow marshal a method call back to the UI thread and then update the existing form instance on that thread.  There are a couple of ways that can be done:

1. Have access to the existing form object and call its Invoke method.
2. Use the `SynchronizationContext` class to marshal the method call to the UI thread and then use the default instance.

Comment: simple hack: maintain a `Shared` reference to `Form1`.

Comment: @porkchop, that's a quick and dirty solution that would work but it's not one to be proud of.  When you have the opportunity, it's best to learn the right way to do things rather than settling for a simple hack.

Comment: that's why i called it a hack, and you really must be careful with that sort of thing ;p

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks, I tried using SynchrnizationContext, but i'm not much familiar with Threading concept, i'm still not able to implement it in my code.

Comment: If I don't know what you did then I can't know what you did wrong but here's a quick example of using `SynchronizationContext`: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387-Accessing-Controls-from-Worker-Threads&p=3815520&viewfull=1#post3815520

Comment: @jmcilhinney i have just edited the code. can you please check it and let me know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
Class myClass
    Friend TB As TextBox
    Class myThread
        ' ...
    End Class
End Class

Class Form1
    Overrides Sub OnLoad
        _tcpClient = New myClass
        Controls.Add(_tcpClient.TB)
        _tcpClient.doSomething()
    End Sub
End Class
```

like that, as per my comments.